# CSS hover changing style of other text / class doesn't work if within a table cell

Tags: css, html-table, hover, cell

I have some text, and I would like it so that certain other bits of text within the same page change font color, when hovering over the initial text.

For example, with the code below, when hovering over the "Hover over me" text, I would like it to change the font color of the two spans with `class="span2"` to red.

Annoyingly, it doesn't want to do this if the span is within a table cell:

```
<style type="text/css">
.span1:hover ~ .span2 {
    color: red;
}
</style>

<span class="span1">Hover over me</span>
<br>
<span class="span2">This font colour changes as required.</span>
<br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="span2">This font colour doesn't change, why?</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried various combinations of adding classes/ids to the td and CSS code, but haven't had any luck, so hopefully someone can provide a solution!

Note:  I don't necessarily need it to work outside AND inside a table cell, in fact, I only really need it to work inside a table cell, but there will be multiple occurrences of the text spread over different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here has to do with the `~` selector. It only selects subsequent siblings and not children of siblings. This is why it works on your first line, and not the one nested in the table. Here is a handy list of [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) that I find helpful.

Unfortunately there isn't a way to solve this purely with CSS without changing the way your html is laid out. You could try something like:

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 //all your existing html
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper:hover .span2 {
    color: red;
}
```

Or you could keep your current html, and go a jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.span1').hover(
      function () {
          $('.span2').css('color', 'red');
      }, function () {
          $('.span2').css('color', 'black');
      }
   );
});
```

Here is a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/K8fg9/)** of both.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work:

`<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.span3').hover(
        function () {
            $('.span4').css('color', 'red');
        }, function () {
            $('.span4').css('color', 'white');
        }
    );
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="span3">Hover over me with JS</span>
    <br>
    <span class="span4">This font colour changes as required.</span>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="span4">This font colour doesn't change</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>`

Comment: Apologies, I'm not entirely sure how to display code properly in a comment.  I should note that I have the "jquery-1.11.0.min.js" file in the same directory as the page, and the above code is all within the body tag.  I also added the wrapper div CSS, although I think that is not meant to be used in this instance anyway.

Comment: I suspect my page isn't installing jQuery correctly, as the code above works on JSFiddle, but not on my webpage.  I've also tried moving the script src="... into the head tags, but still no luck.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, could you please take a look?  Nothing changes in the link for me: http://www.codjumper.com/hover.php

Comment: @user3294858, it looks like your example is lacking a `$(document).ready();`. The fiddle includes this automatically. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason that if you wrap `<span class="span2">This font colour changes as required.</span>` in a `div` (e.g. `<div><span class="span2">This font colour changes as required.</span></div>` even the first `.span2` won't turn red!  Because it doesn't match your css rule!

Doing something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9a9S2/) will work for you:

CSS (your rule UNchanged):

```
.span1:hover .span2 {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML (wraps all `.span2` within `.span1`):

```
<span class="span1">Hover over me
    <br />
    <span class="span2">This font colour changes as required.</span>
    <br />
    <span>This should not be red</span>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="span2">This font colour doesn't change, why?</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

Comment: Tables aren't allowed within span elements.  But, your basic premis is good.  If span1 was a parent, that simplifies things.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't validate (violates block inside inline),  but it works. Just change the `span` to a `div`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that CSS can perform this kind of functionality.

Jquery could definitely handle this feature, if you're not opposed to using it.  A simple onhover event that would manipulate the css you want would work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your span1 always going to be a sibling of the table you want to find span2 in?  If so,

```
.span1:hover ~ table tr td .span2 {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S5VAp/
But, if span1 is another td in the table, or if your tables become nested, it becomes more difficult.  In that case a javascript solution would be much more straight forward.

Comment: span1 (which only occurs once) will be in a completely different table to occurrences of span2, I'm afraid!

Comment: Actually, it turns out that your code above works - even when I have duplicates of span2 in different tables, all occurrences change color.  Thank you very much!

Comment: But if you put span1 within a table (instead of the tables being a sibling of span1), my code won't work. http://jsfiddle.net/S5VAp/1/

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean.  Back to the drawing board!

Comment: I think @badAdviceGuy's jQuery solution is the way I'd go.

Comment: Okay thank you, although I'm having trouble implementing his solution (see above).

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem where the table row will highlight correctly but the font color inside each td tag stayed the same.

Problem:

```
tr:hover {
    background: #0585fd;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Fix:

```
tr:hover td {
    background: #0585fd;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Adding the td to the tr:hover pseudo made the text inside the td tag turn white on hover for the entire row.